# how set "app:layout_columnWeight" from code?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to assign the attribute "app:layout_columnWeight" from code. I tried to "GridLayout.LayoutParams" and apply a style to a template. I need to use this attribute because "android:layout_columnWeight" does not work in Api <21.

PS: I'm using android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout not android.widget.GridLayout.

I attached the picture:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**  not exactly, I've tried many things ...

Layout-frame template (sample):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fonfo_monstruo"
    style="@style/monstruo">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="none"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Frame style:

```
<style name="monstruo"  >
<item name="android:layout_margin" >5dp</item>
<item xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" name="layout_columnWeight" >1</item>
</style>
```

Grid on main XML layout:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="3"
    android:background="#cbb5ff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />
```

---

onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout grid= (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams params=new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.height=200;
    params.width=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        View newMonster=View.inflate(this,R.layout.layu_mosnter,null);
        newMonster.setLayoutParams(params);
        grid.addView(newMonster);
    }

}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Can you post any?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
I edited with code something like that, I do not have the original because I have changed many times.

Answer (score 3):

I have the problem too, my solution is：

```java
GridLayout.Spec spec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1.0f);
GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(new MarginLayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ItemView itemView = newChildView(mGridLayout);
lp.columnSpec = spec;
mGridLayout.addView(itemView, lp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
((GridLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams()).columnSpec =
    GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f);
```

if view have been add to layout

or in your code:

replace

```
 android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams params=new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams();
```

with

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),  GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
```

Comment: I tried that but that only works in API>=21. That's the problem. Yes, i wrote all reference for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a "RecyclerView" is more efficient, if someone wants the code that asks me.

Answer (score 0):

after this

```
grid.addView(newMonster);
```

add

```
((android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams) newMonster.getLayoutParams()).columnSpec = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f);
```

So if U want use new LayoutParams just create it every time with params:

```
   import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        View newMonster = View.inflate(this, R.layout.frame, null);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED), GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f));
        params.height = 200;
        params.width = 0;
        newMonster.setLayoutParams(params);
        grid.addView(newMonster);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but that only works in API>=21. That's the problem.

Comment: I use support lib and it fine work at least on api 19.

Comment: Updated answer when need use new LayoutParams